# Python: raise another exception in except block to catch later

Tags: python, exception

I want something like this:

```py
trigger = True
try:
    x = my_function()  # This can raise IndexError
    if x is None:
        raise ValueError
except IndexError:
    trigger = False
    raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    do_something()
```

I want `trigger` to be False when IndexError is raised, and `do_something()` to happen both if IndexError is raised, or the return value of `my_function()` is None. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is as follows:

```
trigger = True
try:
    x = my_function()  # This can raise IndexError
    if x is None:
        raise ValueError
except (ValueError, IndexError) as e:
    if type(e) is IndexError:
        trigger = False
    do_something()
```

Otherwise, you may re-raise an error, but you will need nested `try` block, and I assume you don't want that.